# read all content in UL and display in alert box

Tags: javascript, html

i have done a coding on list. in the list it also can add new list through javascript. How can i read entire an UL list and display it into javascript alert message when i click on button.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/SJxtfQ9JV - this the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will read all the items in the **my-list** ul and display them in an alert.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#my-list li");
var i, l, alertMessage = '';
l = lis.length;


for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  alertMessage += i + ". " + lis[i].textContent + "\n";
}

alert(alertMessage);
```

```html
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```